# How to get a total count when also grouping in sql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to get a COUNT for a mysql query. Its pretty simple:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE [insert rule here] GROUP BY grouper
```

The problem is because of that group by at the end, I end up getting a count of rows for each group, when I simply want a total.

Currently to do this I'll put the results in an array from a query that looks more like this:

```
$res = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM table WHERE [insert rule here] GROUP BY grouper)
$count = mysql_num_rows($res);
```

This works ok, but I'd just like to use COUNT.

How is this accomplished?

Comment: Without getting too in to overhead or dramatic queries, I'd say you're on the right track counting the return rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `WITH ROLLUP` after your group by statement: `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE [insert rule here] GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP`

Comment: thats cool. it then adds up all the numbers and the last one is the total. but how to access that number?

Comment: The summary row will be indicated by a `NULL` value in the grouped column.  you just look through the result set, and find the row where the grouped column is null, then read the value of the count column from that row.  In the case of a single grouped column, the summary row will also always be the last row returned - so alternately, you could find it that way.

Answer (score 1):

at the risk of sounding stupid (or misinterpreting your question):

remove the `group by` clause?

Comment: in this situation i'm counting the sum total of visits grouped by a session_id. ie the accurate result is something like 50, in this case... without the group by it becomes more like 500.